# implementing bootstrap tabs in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to use Bootstrap tabs with Rails4.1.
Here is my haml code:

```
.container-fluid
  .row-fluid
    .span8.well
      %ul.nav.nav-tabs
        %li.active
          %a{"data-target" => "#home", "data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#home", id: '#home_link'} Home
        %li
          %a{"data-target" => "#profile", "data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#profile", id: '#profile_link'} Profile
      .tab-content
        #home.tab-pane.active.fade.in home tab content
        #profile.tab-pane profile tab content
```

In my application.js i have

```
//= require bootstrap
```

For the first time loading page it show home tab content but afterwards clicking on any tab doesn't show anything. I don't know where I am lacking. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it myself through

```
.container-fluid
  .row-fluid
    .span8.well
      %ul.nav.nav-tabs
        %li.active
          %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#home"} Home
        %li
          %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#profile"} Profile
        %li
          %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#messages"} Messages
        %li
          %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#settings"} Settings
      / Tab panes
      .tab-content
        #home.tab-pane.active 1
        #profile.tab-pane 2
        #messages.tab-pane 3
        #settings.tab-pane 4
```